# Does anyone know why OS X has problems with Image Editor?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texture-painting, uv-image-editor, osx

I am trying to use the UV/Image Editor to texture paint and this is all I am able to see. The first image is when I opened the file and the second is when I zoomed in. I have done a render on a different program and while it was rendering the same visual problems arose, but the image rendered and saved fine. Any ideas what causes this?
[image: Startup]
[image: Zoom]

My system information:

Blender 2.79

Model Name: Mac Pro
  Model Identifier: MacPro1,1
  Processor Name:   Dual-Core Intel Xeon
  Processor Speed:  2.66 GHz
  Number Of Processors: 2
  Total Number Of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per processor): 4 MB
  Memory:   18 GB
  Bus Speed:    1.33 GHz
  Boot ROM Version: MP11.005C.B08
  SMC Version (system): 1.7f10

Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce 7300 GT 256MB VRAM

Comment: I have no issues on a similar system here - can you double check the nvidia driver first and then also check if there is an OS update?

Comment: I could not find a nVidia update, and there are no updates for my current OS

System Version: Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 10.8.0